# Working of MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently want to write a query(MySQL) that satisfies the following conditions

1. Return all rows in which (Column1 != 5 or Column1 != 12  or Column1 != 8 )
2. Return all rows in which Column2 != 300
3. Return all rows in which Column3 = 200

So I wrote the following query which on works fine on only two rows but I wanted to make sure that this query is correct

```
SELECT * MyTable
    WHERE (Column1 != 5 AND Column1 != 12 AND Column1 != 8)
        AND Column2!=300
        AND Column3=200;
```

Is there a better way to write this. Any chances of deficiency in this query ?

Comment: Can't you view the data that your query is retuning and see for yourself whether it's correct? You can create a test table with all values between 1 and 1000 and see if these are returned in your select... then you _know_.

Comment: Those are three different queries. Do you want to return only rows that satisfies all three? Any one of the three?

Comment: I am trying to return a query that satisfies all of them

Comment: @Ben it is returning the right values . I just want to know if there is a better way. for this and apparently juergen answer shows that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT * MyTable 
where Column1 not in (5, 8, 12)
and Column2 <> 300 
and Column3 = 200;
```

Comment: is there a difference between != and <>

Comment: != and <> perform the same function.   Some programming languages support one or both.    MySql supports both...